# Unrecognized Selector Sent To Instance, iPhone Error

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, unrecognized-selector, method-invocation

I get the error

> "012-02-10 13:54:52.570 HelloWorld[14275:10103]
>   -[HelloWorldViewController buttonPressed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6cc0c50 2012-02-10 13:54:52.572 HelloWorld[14275:10103]
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[HelloWorldViewController
>   buttonPressed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6cc0c50'".

This is the offending text:

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    NSString *text = [button titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSLog(@"%@",text);
}
```

I know this because if I change the code to this:

```
-(void)buttonPressed {
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
}
```

It then works correctly.

However I need the text from the component that sent the message. The components are not drag and dropped with IB. They are allocated, initialized and placed in the loadView method. To each of my buttons I have added buttonPressed as the action listener.

Comment: Could you show the code that adds the action listener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error **unrecognized-selector** could be due to a missing `:`.

```
[yourbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

instead of

```
[yourbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In the first case you call `-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender`. In the second instead you call `-(void)buttonPressed`.

But if you provide more code for your `UIButton`, it could be simpler to understand what is going on.

Comment: It should be noted that this answer is also applicable in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

In the first (not working) case you have `-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender` and in the second (working) you have `-(void)buttonPressed`. Obviously your button calls the function without argument.

Answer (score 1):

that could be the case when you have added the `@selector(buttonPressed:)` for button touch event, you have forgotten to put the `:` with method name.

you can check for the same.